# Getting root directory contents

Tags: android, directory-structure, file-management

I have an app with data stored (by previous developer) in user-based directories: `context.getDir(userLoginHash, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`. And there is no users list - when user logs in app tries to load contents of his directory (or creates new one), when user logs out directory remains on the device.

And now I wan't to clean the data. So I need to get list of such folders, but didn't find method for that. It confused me a lot because task looks too obvious. Do I miss something? How can I do this?

Comment: Please, comment when you downvote to let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I need to get list of such folders, but didn't find method for that

There is nothing really built-in for that.

> How can I do this?

Start with:

```
File motherOfAllUserDirectoriesAndOtherStuff = getDir("whatever", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getParentFile();
```

You can iterate over all of the contents of `motherOfAllUserDirectoriesAndOtherStuff` using standard Java I/O (e.g., `listFiles()`). However, bear in mind that not everything in `motherOfAllUserDirectoriesAndOtherStuff` will be your user directories. `SharedPreferences`, databases, other files, etc. will also be in there. You will need to devise an algorithm that can determine whether a subdirectory of `motherOfAllUserDirectoriesAndOtherStuff` is one of your user directories or not, perhaps based on what a hash looks like.

If you can someday rewrite this, create your own root and put the user directories in there. IOW:

```
File userDir = new File(getDir("myAppRoot", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), userLoginHash);
```

Comment: Thanks. The last thing was the main idea of this cleanup. Will wait a bit and apply your answer as correct.